# cmake: setting default values for arguments

Tags: cmake

My UNIX Makefile is as follows:

```
   param=0

   run:
       ./foo -r "fun($(param))"
```

So if I do `make run`, I get `./foo - r "fun(0)"` and
for `make run param=10`, I get `./foo -r "fun(10)"`.

Now I want to generate similar Makefile using cmake.

```
   add_custom_target(
    run 
    ./foo -r "\"fun($(param))\""
   )
```

How do I set the default value for `param` within cmake configuration file?

Comment: I don't think it's possible because CMake designed to be used with any type
of build system, and, for example, what will work for `make` will have no
sense for `msvc`. May be use some cross-platform solution, like reading variable
from file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concept in CMake is a bit different. You can define "cache variables" (basically variables that are remembered for subsequent builds in the same build dir, and can be customized by users) that come with default values and documentation strings and such. These can then be changed either by passing `-D name:type=value` options to cmake, or using one of the friendlier frontends (e.g. `ccmake`, the curses UI for CMake).

Example based on your question:

```
SET(param 0 CACHE STRING "Test variable defaulting to '0'")
# ...
add_custom_target(run ./foo -r "\"fun(${param})\"")
```

You'll find more details in the exhaustive docs for CMake.

PS. this is for variables inside CMake and specifically `CMakeLists.txt` itself; the possibility to change the value is not carried over into the generated Makefile as far as I can tell. I'm not sure that's possible in the first place because it probably wouldn't be compatiable with all of the targets supported by CMake (e.g. Visual Studio projects and what not). In any case, CMake doesn't seem to have been designed for generating build files used independently of CMake.

Comment: I had the same thoughts as in your update. Maybe it's possible to add a custom line when generating specific (for example Unix) Makefile.

Comment: @nil It's possible to add custom build rules, using `add_custom_command`, but I don't see a way to set a default for the variable at the top level of the `Makefile`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
set (projectname_param 0)
```

to set it.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. `param` value is not replaced. I get `./foo -r "fun()"`.