# How to create a CMake variable that takes a default value unless explicitly overridden?

Tags: c++, build, cmake, default

I have a C++ project that is built using CMake. I would like the build configuration in CMakeLists.txt to be such that it builds in `Release` mode by default, and builds in `Debug` mode only when explicitly specified.

Referring to [this](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/command/set.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19911494/5987698), to allow the build type to be specified from the command line, I have set the variable as follows:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING "")
```

However, this caches the build type from the last build, so if the last build was `Debug`, I need to explicitly specify `Release` in the next build.

I tried using `FORCE` and also tried adding

```
unset(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE CACHE)
```

before the `set()`, but both these methods fix the value to `Release` and override the value specified by the user.

Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you.

---

The following is an MCVE:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
project(Test LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release CACHE STRING "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -DDEBUG")

file(GLOB SOURCES *.cpp)

add_executable(test ${SOURCES})
```

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
#ifdef DEBUG
    std::cout << "Debug defined" << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << "Debug not defined" << std::endl;
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

To build, I use

```
cmake .
make
```

The first step could have `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` for `Debug` mode.

Answer (score 24):

You can use something like this:

```
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif()
```

That way, if nothing is specified to CMake, it will use whatever value you set here, and the provided value otherwise.

To prevent this from being used for all the subsequent builds, add

```
unset(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE CACHE)
```

towards the end of your script, so that it removes any cached value and rely on either the default or the provided one.

Comment: Thank you, but this did not work. If I set to Debug using `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`, subsequent builds use the Debug mode, instead of the Release mode, as required.

Comment: You mean that if you do a build that specifies `Debug`, and then another build with nothing specified, it builds in `Debug` mode again instead of `Release`? Are you sure there's no more caching in your `CMakeLists.txt`? Also, this works for the steps where CMake reads the CMakeLists and generate files for the build (e.g. a Makefile), not for the build itself.

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening. I am using exactly the inputs I have specified in the question. For build, a Makefile is generated and the program is built using GNU Make. I have also added the build steps to the question. Thank you.

Comment: @GoodDeeds You could use the code from this answer, but in addition put `unset(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE CACHE)` somewhere at the end of your CMake script. This way the user has to set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` every time CMake is run, otherwise the default value (Release) is used.

Comment: @RaulLaasner Ah good catch! I usually remove all CMake generated files when building over or switching configuration, which meant I didn't have to use that. This fixes it.